# Using Javascript to submit a form with multiple submit buttons as a user

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to figure out (on the client side) how to use javascript to submit a specific submit button for a form with multiple submit buttons.

Currently,

```
            document.forms[0].submit()
```

does not seem to be working because it submits the first submit button instead of the second one, which is what I want to be submitted.

Is there a way to submit only the second submit button?

Here is an example of the buttons:

```
            <input type="submit" class="submitButton_1" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"
               title="Cancel" name="cancel"/>

            <input type="submit" class="submitButton_2 "  id="Button" value="Test"
                   title="Test" name="TestButton"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*submitting a button*"?

Comment: What's that "Cancel" supposed to do?  Could you replace it with a "Reset"?  Ex.:  <input type="reset" class="submitButton_1" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" title="Cancel" name="cancel"/>

Comment: @chipChocolate.py—that will submit the second form, the OP wants to submit the first form but with the second submit button.

Comment: Call the second button's click method: `document.forms[0].TestButton.click()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('whatever-id-here').click();
```

will "click" on the button with ID `whatever-id-here`

Comment: More appropriate for the OP is likely `document.forms[0].cancel.click()` or  `document.forms[0].TestButton.click()`.